# TreeView - different image for roots and subnodes

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a treeView in my WPF application. It's supposed to have only two levels, some roots and their child nodes. I want the roots to have the image "project.png" and the child nodes to have the image "layout.png". The tree is built dynamically, here's the xaml:

```
<TreeView Name="trvMenu" Grid.Column="0" MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

I need to add something like: `<Image Source="...` but I need two different images to different levels in the tree. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to bind the image source to a property on the View Model for the item - e.g. you already bind `Title`, you want to bind `Image.Source` to something like `IconUri`

So, the example XAML:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding IconUri, Mode=OneWay}" Height="16" Width="16" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And in the ViewModel, something like:

```
public string IconUri
{
    get { return "pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/project.png"; }
}
```

Root node ViewModels would return the path to project.png, child node ViewModels would return the path to layout.png.

Comment: So in this IconUri I need to check if it's a root or not and return the suitable image?

Comment: Yeah, either do something like that or whatever creates the viewmodel in the first place could set IconUri based on what it knows up-front.  Both should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! Last question, how do I combine it with the xaml?